# Python password_strength package and password "strength"

Tags: python, passwords, password-protection, password-strength

I'm using the `password_strength` package from PyPi to assess password strength, using a policy of `PasswordPolicy.from_names(strength=x)`.

The package documentation suggests that `x=0.66` is a good choice.  I've set up a random password generator, producing passwords containing upper- and lower-case letters, numerals and special symbols.  For this password to pass `strength=0.66`, it needs to be 15 characters long.  Is that what we're really advocating these days for website passwords?

To get that down to eight random characters, I have to set `strength=0.25`.  I don't really have much grasp of what this "strength" number means, but that seems a long way below the recommendation.

Can someone explain what this number is in words a simpleton like me can understand?  What's a reasonable number for a website password these days?

**Edit** The answer is really making me wonder if password strength is an appropriate measure to use.  According to this, `qwerty123` has exactly the same strength as `m#U0(Bp94`.

Answer (score 0):

Strength is simply a logical scoring of passwords whose values ranges from [0, 1] which means weak and strong password repectively.Password strength is a measure of the effectiveness of a password against guessing or brute-force attacks.

So if you try

```
from password_strength import PasswordStats

stats = PasswordStats('qwerty123')
print(stats.strength())  #-> Its strength is 0.316

stats = PasswordStats('G00dPassw0rd?!')
print(stats.strength())  #-> Its strength is 0.585

stats = PasswordStats('V3ryG00dPassw0rd?!')
print(stats.strength())  #-> Its strength is 0.767
```

Now say you have a use case where you need to create a password policy for testing passwords and say you only want to filter those passwords which scores a strength greater than 0.5, for that you would have to  set Password policy with strength 0.50

```
policy = PasswordPolicy.from_names(
    strength=0.50  # need a password that scores at least 0.5 with its strength
)
```

Say you have a password which has a score of 0.316 (`qwerty123`) then the below code would give you Strength value and EntropyBits if it does **not** match your password policy. (A non empty list)

```
print(policy.test('qwerty123'))
# [Strength(0.5, 30)]
```

In case it **passes** the password policy you would get an empty list, eg

```
print(policy.test('YCw9qDog8Zn20QD'))             
# []  - good password; it actually scored 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks.  I could see how to test passwords.  I'll update the question with my test code.

Comment: @Tom, if my answer helped you, could you please consider accepting the same

Answer (score 0):

You have two aspects to consider:

- the first one is strength, defined as a function of the "entropy bits" value checked against a minimum value which defaults to 30. Since the entropy bits are computed as `password_length * log2(alphabet_length)` where the alphabet is composed of the distinct chars in the password, you will need at least a 10-chars password with at most one repeated char. 9-char passwords, even with no repetition, will always be "too weak": `9*log(9,2)` is just `28.53`
- the second one is the "weakness factor", defined as the lenght of repeating patterns ("blahblah") and/or substrings belonging to sequences ('abcd', '123', 'qwerty') divided by the total password length, and capped to 1.0. So a weakness factor of 1.0 means the whole password has weakness issues, a factor of 0.0 means there are no such issues at all.

Summing up, `qwerty123` and `m#U0(Bp94` have the same entropy; but the former has a weakness factor of 1.0 and the latter of 0.0.

What can you do:

- modify the entropy bits threshold:

```
from password_strength import PasswordStats as pwdstats
stats1=pwdstats('qwerty123')
stats2=pwdstats('m#U0(Bp94')

>>> stats2.strength() #the values here are the same for stats1 and stats2
0.31699249982723876

>>> stats2.strength(weak_bits=20)
0.5386902793854662

>>> stats2.strength(weak_bits=15)
0.694019299386392
```

- Combine strength and weakness factor:

```
>>> (1-stats1.weakness_factor)*stats1.strength(weak_bits=15) #very bad pwd
0.0

>>> (1-stats2.weakness_factor)*stats2.strength(weak_bits=15) #very good pwd
0.694019299386392
```